# Need logs for the data entered in oracle

Tags: oracle, logging, plsql, oracle11g

I have entered the data in one of the table present in oracle database

Table name is TABLE1 and it has 3 columns i.e. (ROLL_NO, NAME, AGE)

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1
(
   ROLL_NO NUMBER NOT NULL,
   NAME VARCHAR2(10),
   AGE NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES(1, 'BOB', 20);
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES(2, 'TOM', 21);
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES(3, 'SAM', 22);
```

I just want the logs of the data entered in oracle. How can I get the logs for these data entered

Comment: What "logs" are you looking for?  You could enable auditing on the table before doing the inserts and then look at the audit data.  You could use LogMiner to mine the redo logs that Oracle generates for the insert statements (assuming you retain all the redo logs you would need to do this examination).  You could create a trigger on the table that logs modifications to a separate history table.  It all depends on what problem you are really trying to solve.

Comment: I just need the logs like who, when and what time this data is entered.

Comment: Is the "who" in this case the Oracle user that executed the `insert`?  Normally, people are looking for the application user which Oracle won't know.  Do you need this immediately after doing the inserts in a toy environment with little else going on?  If so, LogMiner is quite reasonable.  Or do you need to get this information years later in a production environment?  In which case, LogMiner would be vastly too cumbersome.  Can you add columns to track this to the table?  Can you create a separate history table?

Comment: In prod environment, someone entered the data in oracle today (which shouldn't enter basically) and we got to know that the data is present in oracle database after 1 week so I  need the logs of it.

Comment: Is the "who" in this case the Oracle user that executed the insert? Normally, people are looking for the application user which Oracle won't know.   Are you looking for information from today?  Or from a week ago?  I assume a prod environment is in `archivelog` mode.  Do you have the archived logs from the time when the data was entered?

Comment: Oracle doesn't audit at the data level by default. This is because auditing is an overhead, and the more granular the audit trail the higher the overhead.  Consequently, t's something we need to enable ourselves. Of course, as you're in the process of discovering, not having an active audit trail comes with its own costs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an extra table in order to retain those DML logs such as

```
CREATE TABLE log_table1
(
   id          NUMBER,
   dml_type    VARCHAR2(1),
   roll_no     NUMBER,
   name        VARCHAR2(10),
   age         NUMBER,
   client_info VARCHAR2(64), 
   osuser      VARCHAR2(128), 
   module      VARCHAR2(64),
   machine     VARCHAR2(64),
   time        DATE 
);
/
```

and a database trigger to populate that table along with a sequence to generate identity value for each record such as

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq_table1;
/
```

and then

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_log_table1
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  v_dml_type     VARCHAR2(1):='I';
  v_client_info  v$session.client_info%TYPE;
  v_osuser       v$session.osuser%TYPE;
  v_module       v$session.module%TYPE;
  v_machine      v$session.machine%TYPE;
BEGIN
    SELECT client_info, osuser, module, machine
      INTO v_client_info, v_osuser, v_module, v_machine
      FROM v$session
     WHERE sid = sys_context('USERENV','SID');

  IF inserting OR updating THEN
    IF updating THEN v_dml_type := 'U'; END IF;
    INSERT INTO log_table1
    VALUES(seq_table1.nextval,v_dml_type,:new.roll_no,:new.name,:new.age,v_client_info, v_osuser, v_module, v_machine,SYSDATE);
  ELSIF deleting THEN
    v_dml_type := 'D';
    INSERT INTO log_table1
    VALUES(seq_table1.nextval,v_dml_type,:old.roll_no,:old.name,:old.age,v_client_info, v_osuser, v_module, v_machine,SYSDATE);
  END IF;
END;
/
```

If you get **null** values for `client_info` and `module` for some rows, probably need to call those procedures

```
dbms_application_info.set_module(i_module,i_action);
dbms_application_info.set_client_info(i_client);
```

from the application from which you reach the database in order to populate those columns.